# FileNotFound Exception when run on docker

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I have an ASP.Net Core Web API application in which I am accessing a file which is in a folder called "Data" at the same level as "Controllers" folder. It works perfectly fine when I run the application without docker. But when I run application on docker it just throws an error.

Upon inspecting the logs with the help of `docker logs <containerid>` I found the following:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HMB6BABGSIF7", Request id "0HMB6BABGSIF7:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/app/.\Data\petronas.xlsx'.
File name: '/app/.\Data\petronas.xlsx'
   at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
```

**Following is my Docker file:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY ./ ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
COPY Data ./Data
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000  
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Validator.dll"]
```

**Code to access the file:**

```
var lineitems = ConvertExcelToDataTable(@".\Data\petronas.xlsx");
```

Comment: how are you accessing you file your code ?

Comment: @aamd I have added the code.

Comment: Seems like your dev'ing on Windows and `\Data\petronas.xlsx` will need to be changed to `/Data/petronas.xlsx` on the container... I'm not remembering right now what the dotnet containers are based on, but, its Linux if I'm remembering correctly. Also, when you are out of your intermediate container, you can use the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1` image instead of the sdk... it is optimized for running aspnet core apps and should be smaller as well.

Answer (score 0):

in linux path separator is `/` you can change you filePath to `./Data/pertonas.xlsx` it will work on both linux and windwos. be aware paths are case sensitive in Linux

Comment: Instead of hard-coding it for one platform or other, use something like [`Path.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.join?view=net-5.0) or [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0) to let .NET worry about the platform's details.